# How to do a count in Bigquery for how many devices are connected to a model?

Tags: count, google-bigquery

I am currently running a query that selects a distinct model type, sorts it by serial # and adds up the connection time that that device has been used for. I also want to add to it to count how many devices are being used for each model. Device is represented by DeviceID which is a string

```
Select Serial, MAX(createdAt),
SUM(ConnectionTime) as Total 
FROM [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.testf] 
Where Model In
  (Select Model 
  From [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.testf]
  Where Model == "BlueBox-pH")
Group BY Serial
LIMIT 1000
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` but make sure to use standard SQL since legacy SQL will not give you an exact count. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Serial,
  MAX(createdAt) AS Latest,
  SUM(ConnectionTime) as Total,
  COUNT(DISTINCT Model) AS Devices
FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.testf`
WHERE Model = "BlueBox-pH"
GROUP BY Serial
ORDER BY Serial
LIMIT 1000;
```

Since the filter includes only a particular model, though, this would just give you a count of 1 for each serial number.